# Ios 7 Core Data refreshing modal view for multiple entries

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have created a core data model and it works fine, I am loading data into a main view which has a relationship to a subview (table). In the subview I load a Modal view through a segue and then add data to a subview(table). My issue is I want to save the data to the store without dismissing the modal view so the user can do multiple entries before dismissing the view. So my question is how to save to the store, reset the view and refresh the object that I have passed into this modal view without dismissing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the context to the modal view in the prepareForSegue then you should be able to save from your modal view

Comment: Thanks for you quick response, yes I have passed the context through the prepareForSeque, I do run the save method from the view controller not the Modal view. But no matter how many times I click the save button it only saves the last entry before the modal view is dismissed.